# Java - proper cancel execution of thread after TimeoutException

Tags: java, multithreading, future

I have a java-program which runs on a schedule and fetches some data from external sources via RFC calls. The RFC calls are threaded and shall be canceled after 60 seconds. This is how I do it:

```
Future<String> future = executor.submit(new MyCallable());
try {
    future.get(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
} catch (TimeoutException e) {
    future.cancel(true);
}
```

This worked for a long time until I came accross a situation, where the external RFC call became stuck and future.cancel(true) was unable to interrupt the thread-execution. So my java-program never finished and continued running until I manually canceled the corresponding process within the external system.

My question now is, how can one guarantee the code to finish in any situation? I saw that stopping the thread is depreciated.

Would it be a good idea to do sth like this?

```
try {
     future.get(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
} catch (TimeoutException e) {
     future.cancel(true);
     if(!future.isDone()){
        System.exit(1);
     }
}
```

Thanks for any ideas on this.

Cheers, Jooo

Answer (score 0):

I believe that there's no way in Java to just kill off a thread if during execution not implemented InterruptedException . If the thread is executing, it just sets a flag and it's up to the thread to notice it. if the thread is waiting or sleeping, it will throw an InterruptedException.

No need  to check after every line, of course, but methods which can take a long time to execute are responsible for properly handling interrupts

kill the process in which the thread is running. (E.g., call System.exit(int).)